# yii-user-management install 404 error

Tags: yii

I am using MAMP pro with yii-1.1.12. and I am trying to install the latest version of yii-user-management.

My route for the webapp is 
/Users/myname/Sites/yii-1.1.12/htdocs

I created the 'modules' folder and copied the yii-user-management into it:

htdocs > protected > modules
(modules and subfolders set to rewrite)

config/main.php

```
'modules'=>array(


    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'password',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

            'modules' => array(
                'user' => array(
                        'debug' => true,
                 )
      ),

),

'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'class' => 'application.modules.user.components.YumWebUser',
                    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                    'loginUrl' => array('//user/user/login'),
    ),
   'import'=>array(
             'application.modules.user.models.*',
           ),
etc...
```

I have followed the instructions to the letter but when I call the user/install in the browser I get a 404 error.
http://yii.dev:8888/index.php/user/install

My page works okay http://yii.dev:8888/index.php/login (with or without index.php)

Very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, are these the instructions you're using?  http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/68/installing-and-configuring-the-yii-user-management-module-under-a-fresh-skeleton-application-generated-by-yiic/

Comment: Yes that's right, though I started from No 3. as I already had a the webapp installed.

Comment: I've never used this module in Yii, but isn't step 6 saying to including the name of the database in the URL?  `http://localhost/testdrive/index.php/user/install`, in this case testdrive?

Comment: That's just the webapp folder I believe. As in 1 and 2.

Comment: You're right, okay, when you browse the /modules/ folder, what does it look like?  It should just be a folder with /user/ in it, correct?  What are the folders inside user?

Comment: yes. inside: assets components controllers docs messages models test UserModule.php vendors views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized there's a problem with your config/main.php...

You have modules listed within modules:

```
'modules'=>array(
  'gii'=>array(//...gii configuration...),
  'modules' => array(
    'user' => array(
    'debug' => true,
  )
),
```

It should just be:

```
'modules'=>array(
  'gii'=>array(//...gii configuration...),
  'user' => array(
    'debug' => true,
  )
),
```